# Mocha tests fail when being run from gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, mocha.js

I have developed a suite of tests for my application's service level classes, and all of them pass when being run in mocha ie:

mocha testfile.js

However when I run them from gulp, I get timeout errors for every test in one of the files:

1) booking service should create booking:
     Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.

2) booking service should cancel booking:
     Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.

... and so on for every test

My gulpfile looks like this:

```
var serviceTests = [
  './test/block-service-test.js',
  './test/booking-service-test.js',
  './test/location-service-test.js',
  './test/logging-service-test.js'
];

gulp.task('serviceTests', function(){
  gulp.src(serviceTests)
    .pipe(mocha()) 
    .on('end', function() { console.log('>>Finished Running Tests'); })
    .pipe(exit());
});
```

The only thing I can figure is that the failing tests are connecting to a database via mongoose. Here's a sample of the setup and one of the tests:

```
process.env.MONGOLAB_URI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/TestDB';
process.env.IN_TEST = true;

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI);

describe("booking service", function() {

    var start = moment(new Date());
    var end = moment(start).add(2, 'h');
    var tutorId = "SomeTutorId";
    var userId = "SomeUserId";

    it("should create booking", function(done){
        return bookingService.createBooking(tutorId, userId,  start, end, "123 Anywhere St", "Test", "User", "Tutor", "LastName")
        .then(function(booking){
            assert.notEqual(booking, null);
            done();
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
            assert.fail();
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Any ideas why they might work from mocha and not gulp?

Comment: Not sure why this question was downvoted? It's a legitimate problem, mongoose should have given an error related to the connection being closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was one test written that was closing the DB connection. Rather than giving a "closed connection" error all mongoose would do is timeout.